# Clojurescript - how to use/import macros in REPL (figwheel)

Tags: clojurescript

I can't seem to use macros in clojurescript REPL.

I define macro in `macros.clj`:

```
(ns clojurescripting.macros)

(defmacro increment [x]
  `(+ 1 ~x))
```

Then I use it in `core.cljs`

```
(ns ^:figwheel-hooks clojurescripting.core
    (:require-macros [clojurescripting.macros]))

(defn main []
      (js/alert (clojurescripting.macros/increment 0)))

(main)
```

The code actually uses `increment` macro, because it gives alert with correct output.

I run repl with `clojure -A:fig:build`.

When I try to use macros in REPL, I can't access the macro - there is no `clojurescripting.core/increment`, and I can't access `clojurescripting.macros` there.

**Another question:** 
Is this possible in any REPL? It seems possible in general, as book *Learning Clojurescript* provide almost identical example, and proceeds to evaluate it in the REPL.

**PS**

This is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12337509/how-can-macros-be-evaluated-using-the-clojurescript-repl) - it is most likely outdated, and the accepted answer is cryptic (I'm not even sure what bREPL is, and whether figwheel uses it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use macros in the REPL, just as you can in code.

The qualified name of the macro in your example is `clojurescripting.macros/increment` (not `clojurescripting.core/increment`), and, presuming the macros namespace has been loaded, you can call the macro (just as is done in the example in your code). Here is an example:

```
cljs.user=> (clojurescripting.macros/increment 0)
1
```

If the macros namespace has not been loaded, you can do that from the REPL by using `require-macros`. Here's an example, that would work even if none of your namespaces were loading the macros namespace:

```
cljs.user=> (require-macros 'clojurescripting.macros)
nil
cljs.user=> (clojurescripting.macros/increment 0)
1
```

You can also use namespace aliases

```
cljs.user=> (require-macros '[clojurescripting.macros :as macros])
nil
cljs.user=> (macros/increment 0)
1
```

and refer macro vars

```
cljs.user=> (require-macros '[clojurescripting.macros :refer [increment]])
nil
cljs.user=> (increment 0)
1
```

All of this should work directly in the REPL.

In fact, all of the variations discussed at https://clojurescript.org/guides/ns-forms should work in the REPL, using `require-macros` in lieu of `:require-macros` and `require` in lieu of `:require`, *etc*.